# Showing data from CSV

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have data in CSV and I am showing it using AJAX, JSON on front end using asp.net but It is not indexed in search engine. Is there alternative way to show data from CSV on front end so that it is indexed in search engines ? What Id data is in XML format as well. Which format should I choose and will it give benefit over CSV ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: I need to show it dynamically

Comment: Ok.. so when the page loads, you generate the html table from the data. Or do as Josh said below: As long as you can link to it, it can be crawled.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your file to be indexed it just needs a link to make it publicly available to the web crawler.

You could create a special case to make that file available in IIS, or you could write an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) to serve up the raw contents of the file. Either way, you just need a way for the web crawler to discover the URL, and grab the contents.

Comment: when data is shown using ajax json then it is not indexed in search engines.